# Unable to Append new Child Components in react

Tags: reactjs, plnkr.co

I am new to react.

I want to add another SingleButtonComponent when a SingleButtonComponent is clicked.
I am able to increment the number of children using a state variable numChildren.

```
 AddChild: function() {
       var numChildren = (this.state.numChildren) +1;
       this.setState({numChildren :numChildren}) 
    },
```

But I am getting error whenever I am trying to loop inside

```
 render: function () {
  return ( 
     for (var i = 0; i < this.state.numChildren; i += 1) {
               <SingleButtonComponent AddChild={this.AddChild}/>
        };
  )
}
```

. [Here is the PLUNKER to it](https://plnkr.co/edit/VmJQkQ0pTMmTYYP0Lm4R)

I have temporarily kept the for loop out of render..

Please suggest me a way to add a child-component every time it is clicked.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `render` function doesn't return anything.

If you're using React 16, try:

```
render: function() {
    const arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.numChildren; i += 1) {
        arr.push(<SingleButtonComponent key={i} AddChild={this.AddChild}/>);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Otherwise, you must return a single element:

```
render: function() {
    const arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.numChildren; i += 1) {
        arr.push(<SingleButtonComponent key={i} AddChild={this.AddChild}/>);
    }
    return (<div>{arr}</div>);
}
```

---

Regarding your second question:
`React.createClass` is deprecated in favor of ES6 classes. Your component should be defined as follows:

```
class MainBody extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        this.state = { numChildren: 0 };
    }

    AddChild() { ... }

    render() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ..I replaced the render : by above suggestion and I am now getting MainBody.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Comment: yeah sure...let me check

Comment: yeah that did worked... All i had to change the initial state to  numChildren:1 .. Thanks :)

Comment: and my second question..if you could help... I am gonna vote this as answer :)

Comment: @RohitasBehera There you go